# AceFEM MacOS not responding

Tags: acegen

I just upgraded to v7.114 of AceFEM running on MacOS 10.15.5 and Mathematica 12.0.0.0. I was running v7.101 without a problem. AceGEN seems to work but all AceFEM code starts but does nothing. The notebook states running but nothing is happening. Tried multiple notebooks - same problem.

Comment: Maybe try contacting the developer: https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/acefem/ ?